# C++ Two user input keywords in the same line plus separate checking

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, substring, user-input

I've been trying to get an if statement to work with two key words. Basically my program will check the first word as the "command" word (like get, set, etc), the one that will trigger the specific method, and the second word as the one to search in a list, as an object to use. They must be both writen together in the same line.

I know `getline` can input several words and `cin >> this >> that` also does it. But for separate checking I can't be able to figure it out.
I was advised substrings, but not sure how to do that.

Example:
First word as the command, other as the key to search.

```
if(command == "kick")
{
    std::cin >> input;  //user input "ball"
    person->kick(input) //pointer to function in another class
    ***kicks the ball
}

if(command == "pick")
{
    std::cin >> input; //user input "ball"
    person->pick(input) //pointer to function in another class
    ***picks the ball
}

if(command == "throw")
{
    std::cin >> input;   //user input "paper"
    person->throw(input) //pointer to function in another class
    ***throws the paper
}
```

It works, but my input is supposed:

> kick ball or
>   pick ball

instead of

> kick

ball

and so on.

It's probably super simple, I'm just new to c++.
It must be in the same line of input though, otherwise there would probably be better ways.

Would love some help.
Thanks ;)

Comment: Are you asking how to do `if (input == "kick" && input == "ball")` or something using 2 conditions in your `if` statements?

Comment: No, that would just check both together. Basically it must check the first word as the command word, the one that triggers that specific method. The second word is the one to actually check inside the method and do stuff with it. Because I'll have different methods with different commands, for the same different objects

Comment: With the edit it is clear they are a single string. Once you make the comparison, then do you need to check the second word in the string? Could you have `"kick ball"` and `"kick dog"` that you want to include in an `if (input == "kick") { /* then handle what to kick? */ }`? It looks like you want to use `std::stringstream ss (input);` and then `ss >> cmd >> key;` and act on `cmd` and `key` separately?

Comment: Yes exacly, edited because wasn't explaining properly. Yes that the idea, first word commands what to do with the second word

Comment: Two options. Either before the test split the string into `std::vector<std::string>` or use a `std::stringstream` to separate into `cmd` and `key`, then do `if (cmd == "kick") { switch (key) {....} }` or something similar.

Comment: I eddited a bit further to clarify. Wasn't exatly pointing out what I mean. Sorry about the mess ;)

Comment: Okay, then the same answer still applies. I would either read `std::cin >> cmd >> key;` before any of the `if ()` statements, then it is a simple matter of `if (cmd == "kick") { if (key == "ball") {..} else if (key == "dog") {...} ... }`. Otherwise you can read with `getline()` and then create the `std::stringstream` to separate `cmd / key` and use the same way. The stumbling block you are having is just handling the input. The rest of what you are doing seems reasonable.

Comment: O.T.: You shouldn't name a function or member function `throw`. I'm sure this will produce strange compiler errors. [`throw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/throw) is a keyword with a special meaning.

Comment: What is the data type of `input`? is it char* or string?

Comment: std::string takes the input one by one space seperated. So you can use ```cin>>cmd;``` and then after ```cin>>input;``` . it will save cmd = "kick" and input = "dog"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand that you need to take both the `cmd` and `key` as separate inputs, but the user will enter the string `"cmd key"` and you need to handle each individually, then a simple method is to read each into a `std:string` using the normal `>>` operator, e.g.

```
    std::string cmd, key;

    std::cout << "enter command & key: ";
    if (!(std::cin >> cmd >> key)) {    /* read/validate both cmd & key */
        std::cerr << "stream error or use canceled input.\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

Now you have both `cmd` and `key` stored and can use `cmd` to initially determine what branch to take and then select what action to take based on `key`. For example:

```
    if (cmd == "kick") {        /* handle cmd "kick" */
        if (key == "ball")
            std::cout << "kicking the ball.\n";
        else if (key == "dog")
            std::cout << "kicking the dog.\n";
        else
            std::cout << "generally kicking the " << key << ".\n";
    }
    else if (cmd == "pick") {   /* handle cmd "pick" */
        if (key == "ball")
            std::cout << "picking the ball.\n";
        else if (key == "dog")
            std::cout << "picking the dog.\n";
        else
            std::cout << "generally picking the " << key << ".\n";
    }
    else    /* otherwise unknown command */
        std::cout << "unknown cmd: " << cmd << ".\n";
```

(**note:** you always want to handle the case the user has entered something invalid for each `cmd` or `key` (or both))

Putting it together in a short example, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (void) {

    std::string cmd, key;

    std::cout << "enter command & key: ";
    if (!(std::cin >> cmd >> key)) {    /* read/validate both cmd & key */
        std::cerr << "stream error or use canceled input.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (cmd == "kick") {        /* handle cmd "kick" */
        if (key == "ball")
            std::cout << "kicking the ball.\n";
        else if (key == "dog")
            std::cout << "kicking the dog.\n";
        else
            std::cout << "generally kicking the " << key << ".\n";
    }
    else if (cmd == "pick") {   /* handle cmd "pick" */
        if (key == "ball")
            std::cout << "picking the ball.\n";
        else if (key == "dog")
            std::cout << "picking the dog.\n";
        else
            std::cout << "generally picking the " << key << ".\n";
    }
    else    /* otherwise unknown command */
        std::cout << "unknown cmd: " << cmd << ".\n";
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cmd_select
enter command & key: kick dog
kicking the dog.
```

With command `"pick"`:

```
$ ./bin/cmd_select
enter command & key: pick ball
picking the ball.
```

With unknown command:

```
$ ./bin/cmd_select
enter command & key: shoot dog
unknown cmd: shoot.
```

You can of course pass the string for `cmd` or `key` to a separate function and handle your response to each there, but that is just another way of arranging your code to do the same thing. Look things over and let me know if this is what you were intending. I'm still not 100% clear based on the many edits.

Comment: I'm glad that `shoot dog` was considered as `unknown cmd`. `kick dog` hurts me hard enough. ;-)

Comment: Chuckling -- that was a bit of *tongue-in-cheek* humor `:)`

Comment: Its solved now but your way would work fine,  just not in my case. To be fair, I did not explain things very well. My functions are all inside a while loop, asking input everytime a command is used, so that second cin >> would cause trouble. And I can't change the original cin >>.

I was able to do i this way:

if (maininput == "get") {
                string input = maininput;
                player->get(input.substr(4));
            }

Comment: Okay, so you have a 2-part input. The command first and then then key after you use the `if (command == "kick")` conditional. You can take two separate inputs, `command` before the `if (command == "kick")`, etc.. and then `std::cin >> key;` inside the `if (command == "kick")` block. Glad you got it working.